# How Do I Get The Connection Speed When Connected To Mobile Network?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the connection speed for both Mobile and WiFi connections. I've got WiFi working. Now I need help figuring out the Mobile connection.

Here's what I have so far

```
public void internetConnectionSpeed(Context context) {
    Boolean isConnected = false;
    getConnectionStatus = "Not Connected!";

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
          isConnected = true;
          getConnectionStatus = "Connected!";

          if (isConnected.equals(true)) {
              WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
              WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
              int speedMbps = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
              getConnectionStatus = Integer.toString(speedMbps) + " Mbps";

              //Now I need equivalent code for Mobile Network...
          }

      }else {
          isConnected = false;
          getConnectionStatus = "Not Connected!";
      }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean   connected = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;

if(connected){//todo}
```

> you can't get network speed directly as wifimanager provides. You need
>   to ping in an address and calculate the response time. Follow this:
>   https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib